# Как добавить правило в скрипт, чтобы при определенной ширине экрана изменились некоторые значения

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в нижеприведенном скрипте добавить правило, чтобы при ширине экрана 1200px
значения `minSlides: 4`, и `maxSlides: 4`, изменились на `minSlides: 3`, и `maxSlides: 3`
а при ширине экрана 768px на `minSlides: 2`, и `maxSlides: 2`

Как эту задачу реализовать в виде скрипта?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('[id*=mod_ext_bxslider_k2_content]').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal',  
  randomStart: false,
  minSlides: 4,
  maxSlides: 4,
  slideWidth: 300,
  slideMargin: 32,
  adaptiveHeight: false,
  adaptiveHeightSpeed: 500,
  easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
  speed: 1000,
  controls: true,
  auto: true,
  autoControls: false,
  pause: 7000,
  autoDelay: 0,
  autoHover: true,
  pager: false,
  pagerType: 'full',
  pagerShortSeparator: ' / '
 });
});
```

Когда делаю вот так (как указано ниже) все работает, но по мне это неправильно дублировать все значения и должно быть более изящное решение

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function(){if ($(window).width() <= 1200) 
 $('[id*=mod_ext_bxslider_k2_content]').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal',  
  randomStart: false,
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 3,
  slideWidth: 300,
  slideMargin: 32,
  adaptiveHeight: false,
  adaptiveHeightSpeed: 500,
  easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
  speed: 1000,
  controls: true,
  auto: true,
  autoControls: false,
  pause: 7000,
  autoDelay: 0,
  autoHover: true,
  pager: false,
  pagerType: 'full',
  pagerShortSeparator: ' / '
 });
});


$(window).on('load resize', function(){if ($(window).width() <= 768) 
 $('[id*=mod_ext_bxslider_k2_content]').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal',  
  randomStart: false,
  minSlides: 2,
  maxSlides: 2,
  slideWidth: 300,
  slideMargin: 32,
  adaptiveHeight: false,
  adaptiveHeightSpeed: 500,
  easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
  speed: 1000,
  controls: true,
  auto: true,
  autoControls: false,
  pause: 7000,
  autoDelay: 0,
  autoHover: true,
  pager: false,
  pagerType: 'full',
  pagerShortSeparator: ' / '
 });
});
```

Comment: $(window).resize(function(){ If($(window).width() > 1200){ minSlides = 4 } });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

```
var minS  = 4; // minSlides
var maxS  = 4; // maxSlides

    $(window).on('load resize', function(){
        if ($(window).width() <= 768) { minS = 2; maxS = 2; }

        if ($(window).width() >= 1200) { minS = 3; maxS = 3; }

            $('[id*=mod_ext_bxslider_k2_content]').bxSlider({
                mode: 'horizontal',     
                randomStart: false,
                minSlides: minS,
                maxSlides: maxS,
                slideWidth: 300,
                slideMargin: 32,
                adaptiveHeight: false,
                adaptiveHeightSpeed: 500,
                easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
                speed: 1000,
                controls: true,
                auto: true,
                autoControls: false,
                pause: 7000,
                autoDelay: 0,
                autoHover: true,
                pager: false,
                pagerType: 'full',
                pagerShortSeparator: ' / '
            });    

    });
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! То что нужно, работает как и требуется при этом нет лишнего кода!

Comment: А подскажите как правильно добавить дополнительное правило:    `if ($(window).width() <= 480) { minS = 1; maxS = 1; }`
я думаю оно не срабатывает из-за строки `if ($(window).width() <= 768) { minS = 2; maxS = 2; }
` А как правильно добавить чтобы реагировало и на 768 и 480 не хватает знаний ?!

Comment: Извиняюсь за беспокойство) Не знаю на сколько это правильно, но заработало после того как поменял строки местами (сначала правило для 768 потом для 480 потом все что больше 1200 ), вроде работает как надо. Еще раз спасибо за ваш ответ!